# How can I set the background of a transparent image to white, using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a PNG image with transparent background and I want to resize it to another image, but with a white background instead of a transparent one. 
How can I do that with PIL?

Here is my code:

```
basewidth = 200
img = Image.open("old.png")
wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img.save("new.png")
```

Comment: We have made a new edit,go check it

Comment: @Banuta Alin Alexandru first guess would be to try replacing the data[:,:,:,3] with data[:,:,:,4] in the data[:,:,:,3][mask] = [r2,g2,b2,alpha2] line

Comment: Thanks, now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

f = Image.open('old.png') 
alpha1 = 0 # Original value
r2, g2, b2, alpha2 = 255, 255, 255,255 # Value that we want to replace it with

red, green, blue,alpha = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2], data[:,:,3]
mask = (alpha==alpha1)
data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2, alpha2]

data = np.array(f)
f = Image.fromarray(data)
f = f.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

f.save('modified.png', image.format)
```

Comment: I think it will resize and change the color also

Comment: This also doesn't do quite what you want, this replaces all of the black pixels with white. Transparency is encoded in a fourth channel called alpha which for the way you wrote your code would be accessed by 'data[:,:,3]'

Comment: so then change it @Chachmu

Comment: I think it should look something like the edit I just proposed

Comment: thanks I think it will work now what do You think.@Chachmu

Comment: It's been a while since I messed with PIL but as far as I can tell everything is good to go :)

Comment: This appears to rely on a variable, `data` which is undefined in the current edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the alpha channel is set to less than 255 on each pixel (which means that it is not opaque) and then set it to white and opaque.

It might not be an ideal solution if you have transparency in other parts of your image, besides the background.

```
...
pixels = img.load()

for y in range(img.size[1]): 
    for x in range(img.size[0]): 
        if pixels[x,y][3] < 255:    # check alpha
            pixels[x,y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
img.save("new.png")
```

Comment: It's not the ideal solution, because as you said, I can have transparent parts on my image.