# Changing pixel colors in png not working correctly (python, pillow)

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a python script to change the color of text in a png file. Here is an example of an original image [image: original]

Suppose, for example, I want to change the magenta color to blue. My script changes any color that is not black (255,255,255) to blue. My assumption is that this would change the magenta text to blue, since everything else in the image is a different single solid color (read by python as black). Instead, this is the result I get [image: output]

Obviously, this is not correct. I'm kinda stumped. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to solve this problem? This is my first foray into image manipulation with python.

Here is my code

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import*
from math import*
from random import*
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image 

# https://www.codementor.io/isaib.cicourel/image-manipulation-in-python-du1089j1u
#change color 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468530/changing-pixel-color-value-in-pil



image_name = 'Q_test.png'
test_image = 'Q_blue.png'
R1_Path = "C:/Users/PancakeMSTR/Desktop/Keyboard Related/Fusion Keycaps/Cherry/UpdatedLegends/Katakana_Updated/R1/"

image = Image.open(R1_Path+image_name)
image = image.convert('RGB') 
colors = image.getcolors()
pixelMap = image.load() 

newImg = Image.new(image.mode,image.size) 
pixelsNew = newImg.load() 
width,height = newImg.size
for i in range(width): 
    for j in range(height): 
        if pixelMap[i,j] != (255,255,255): 
            pixelsNew[i,j] = (0,0,255)
        else: 
            pixelsNew[i,j] = pixelMap[i,j]
image.close() 
newImg.save(R1_Path+test_image)
```

Thanks! Let me know if any further information is required. Happy to clarify anything I've said.

Comment: Black is (0,0,0). White is (255,255,255)

Comment: It may surprise you to know that your image has 18 unique colours.

Comment: Just checking - did you see my answer? Does it help? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Saving it as a BMP file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The image contains *alpha transparency*, and the large blocks that you see actually appear as such in the original – but the alpha mask hides them. The background that you see as white in this post is not actually white, but fully transparent. Other image viewers may show an even gray, or a gray checkered background.

The problem is introduced almost immediately in your code, because you flatten the image to RGB:

```
image = Image.open(R1_Path+image_name)
image = image.convert('RGB')
```

and now an `image.show()` will show you it is at this exact point the transparency got removed and the large blocks appear.ª

There does not seem to be a reason to convert to RGB, though, because this image already is one; so why not leave it as it is. The only thing is, when you are testing for a not-white pixel, you must **first** test if its underlying color – white *or* anything else – not actually already invisible because of the transparency. Then, only if the pixel is visible, test its color.

Rather than an exact test for 'white' (which you'd need to reconsider anyway, as there is no pure white in this image), I test just one channel here. For other images, this probably will not work and you'd need some heuristic formula – converting the color to grayscale, for example. As this works for your image, I've not investigated that further.

```
from PIL import Image 
image = Image.open('eq2hl.png')
pixelMap = image.load()
newImg = Image.new(image.mode,image.size)
pixelsNew = newImg.load() 
width,height = newImg.size
for i in range(width): 
    for j in range(height):
        pixelsNew[i,j] = pixelMap[i,j]
        if pixelMap[i,j][3] < 250:
            pixelsNew[i,j] = (255,255,255,255)
        elif pixelMap[i,j][0] < 255:
            pixelsNew[i,j] = (0,0,255,255)
newImg.show()
```

... and the result:

[image: transparent/pink image converted to white/blue]

where all almost entirely transparent pixels are replaced with *actual* white, and every not-white pixel replaced with pure blue. This last step, incidentally, also killed the anti-aliasing around the edge, but that's part of the game. It is possible to retain this but it'd a bit more code.

---

ª You could name this an error of PIL's conversion. All the conversion does is throwing away the entire alpha channel. On the other hand, removing alpha *properly* would require you to supply a background color. See [How can I set the background of a transparent image to white, using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39327265/2564301) for an example of how to do that, should you require it.